# Well done you legend!

Tags: word-meaning, colloquial-language

> Well done you legend!

When I translate this phrase, it looks little exaggerated. What does exactly this phrase mean? Can I use this phrase in a serious content or can I only use it in just a casual friendly environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling someone "you legend" is a characteristic of banter between young (20s) British males. It would definitely only be used in a casual context - although that can include work environments in professions such as sales, where this sort of banter is expected.